# Sticky menu wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, sticky

I want to disable the sticky menu of my wordpress site, i'm using the theme swimmingpool & SPA and when I want to customize my theme there is nos customization about the header, i've tried some CSS and it's still not working...

i've tried this :

```
header .container_wrap_menu {
 position: relative !important; 
} 

.master_header {
 position: absolute;
}
```

If anyone got any solution i'll be very happy.

Thx in advance

Comment: I've tryed this :

#header .container_wrap_menu {
position: relative !important;
}

.master_header {

position: absolute;

}

and i want to remove the sticky property i don't want that the menu follow the scroll i want to let the menu on the top of the page.

Comment: how to add the initial menu code ? i can't post the link because the site is under construction :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probleme solved if anyone has the same problem here is the solution :

SP Options -> Misc Settings -> Enable Sticky Header

SET TO OF

Answer (score 0):

If im correct this might help, so go to your css directory , find `swimmingpool.css` the open it.

Search the file for `.topclass.topclass-shrink` and remove `position: fixed;` which keeps it on top for scroll..

(the `class` might be called something else than `.topclass.topclass-shrink` point is to remove `fixed` from the css file, dont overwrite it with `!important` its really bad practice, rather comment out the styling and add new styling to it )

comment out = `//position: fixed`

comment in = `position: relative`

**Tip**: just look at your mobile version im not sure what styling or functionality you have going on since there is not really much provided to work with but just make sure your burger menu shows if you want the menu for mobile. Might want to add a media query and `display` attribute.